# FILE* behvior changes inside a function

Tags: c

I am trying to binary write a struct into file, and then intialize another struct with the second element. 
It works good when I define the FILE *fptr inside the function, but when I pass it from outside as shown, I recieve seg fault in the fread() function. why does it happen? thank for your help in advance!

```
typedef struct Person
{
    int id;
    char name[30];
    int age;
}Person;

int ex3(FILE *fptr);

int main()
{
    FILE *fptr;
    return ex3(fptr);
}
int ex3(FILE *fptr)
{
        Person personArr1[] = {{1, "Seinfeld", 29},
                               {2, "George",   32},
                               {3, "Elain",    28}};
        Person *singlePerson;
        unsigned int i;

        /* write struct into file */
        if (!(fptr = fopen(FILE1, "wb+")))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "COULD NOT WRITE INTO FILE. ABORT.");
            return ERR_CODE;
        }
        fwrite(&personArr1, sizeof(Person), sizeof(personArr1) / sizeof(personArr1[0]), fptr);
        fclose(fptr);

        if (!(fptr = fopen(FILE1, "rb+")))
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "COULD NOT WRITE INTO FILE. ABORT.");
            return ERR_CODE;
        }
        /* go into second element position */
        fseek(fptr, sizeof(Person), SEEK_SET);
        /* initalize new struct values */
        fread(singlePerson, sizeof(Person), 1, fptr);
        fclose(fptr);`enter code here`

        printf("%d %s %d\n", singlePerson->id, singlePerson->name, singlePerson->age);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You have a memory corruption bug.  It is probably nowhere near where you think it is.  Use [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) to find it.  We cannot help you any further unless you show us a [_complete_ program that we can compile and test ourselves](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You need to show the code that calls `ex3`, the problem is most likely _there_.

Comment: Oh, and where does `singlePerson` point to? That's probably the _actual_  problem.

Comment: the other code is just a simple main that calls the function.

Comment: @NissimLevy don't describe your code, but show it. Depending _how exactly_ you call your function you may get into trouble. We need to see the code.

Comment: @zwol well the fptr is clobbered with fopen there.

Comment: Ok, what is this supposed to do!? you're passing in a `fptr` but you're overwriting it with another value from `fopen`.

Comment: okay thank you. this is the full code

Comment: You ignore the value passed into the function since the first thing you do is open a file and assign to the argument. If a function is passed an open file pointer, it should not normally either modify it by opening a file again or close it. You’ve not shown the code that calls your function.

Comment: @NissimLevy it isn't full code it is missing includes. However they weren't necessary here.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I admit I didn't bother reading the code very carefully before I said that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`singlePerson` doesn't point anywhere:

```
Person *singlePerson;
...
fread(singlePerson, sizeof(Person), 1, fptr);
```

So `fread` is attempting to read and dereference an uninitialized pointer.  This invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in your case manifests as crashing sometimes but not others.

You don't need a pointer here.  Just declare `singlePerson` as an instance of `Person` and pass its address.

```
Person singlePerson;
...
fread(&singlePerson, sizeof(Person), 1, fptr);
```

Comment: thank you, it solved the problem. 
still weird that it works fine without this correction, when I define the file pointer inside the function.

Comment: @NissimLevy That's a consequence of undefined behavior.  Reading an invalid pointer will sometimes crash your program and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues:

```
    FILE *fptr;   // here fptr points nowhere
    return ex3(fptr);
```

You pass an invalid pointer to `ex3` and you dereference ith there. But declaring your `fptr` outside `ex3` is pointless anyway.

---

`singlePerson` is never initialized, it points nowhere. You probably want this:

```
Person singlePerson;
```

instead of

```
Person *singlePerson;
```

and call `fwrite` like this:

```
fread(&singlePerson, sizeof(Person), 1, fptr);
```

---